# Forward http requests to https, req.secure not working

Tags: node.js, express

Whenever I hit the URL with HTTP it does not redirect.

server.js:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  console.log('get react app');
  if (req.secure) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html')); 
  }
  else {
    res.redirect(URL);//URL with HTTPS
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you please make a request against your backend with `curl -v` and add the output to your post.